# Python Stacked bar chart from DF with index dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a data frame in python using pandas that has the following output with date being the index:

```
Date        Daily Anger     Daily Haha  Daily Like  Daily Love  Daily Sad   Daily WoW
2019-08-31      1               2.0        132.0        8.0         0.0        5.0
2019-09-30      0               1.0        41.0         4.0         0.0        0.0
2019-10-31      15              1.0        117.0        4.0         0.0        2.0
2019-11-30      0               3.0        84.0         4.0         0.0        4.0
2019-12-31      2               17.0       98.0         20.0        5.0        7.0
```

I'm trying to get these values in a stacked bar chart where the X axis is the date and the y axis is the total values across these metrics

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to get this to work with google with no success. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Date` is column use `x` parameter in [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.plot.bar(x='Date', stacked=True)
```

If `Date` is `DatetimeIndex` use only `stacked` parameter:

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

[image: bar]

Comment: This worked after un-indexing the DF. However, what if I only wanted to have "Daily Haha" and "Daily Like" stacked?

I'm trying to avoid splitting up my DF into multiple sections to make it easier to follow

Comment: @CypherX - If `Date` is index use second simplier solution

Comment: @CypherX - Then if want filter only some columns `df[["Daily Haha", "Daily Like" ]].plot.bar(stacked=True)`

Comment: @CypherX - For first solution `df[["Daily Haha", "Daily Like", 'Date']].plot.bar(x='Date',stacked=True)`

Comment: I feel so silly now! Thanks for the quick response. This solution worked. I'll try googling my other questions.